# requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.RelativeLayout android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapterview

i have implemented listview customadapter when displaying listview it showing below warring how to reslove it .

```
requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.RelativeLayout{b42acc20 V.E..... ......ID 0,-52-480,0 #7f0700ec app:id/ptr_id_header} during layout: running second layout pass
```

java code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitemrow, null);
    }
    RssItem rssItem = mRssItemList.get(position);
    if (rssItem != null)
    {
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowtitle);
        if (title != null)
        {
            title.setText(rssItem.getTitle());
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: This unanswered question might have been resolved on another thread: [Android: requestLayout() improperly called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598977/android-requestlayout-improperly-called)

Answer (score 7):

Is RelativeLayout a layout, you are inflating? If it is, then try to change line

```
 view = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitemrow, null);
```

to this

```
 view = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitemrow, parent, false);
```