# Using View.GONE in a proper and right way

Tags: android

Recently while doing a little project of mine, I applied `View.GONE` in my code and from time to time like randomly I will receive this error below.

```
05-15 15:08:06.426 26589-26589/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{e203993 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00cf app:id/card_location_container} during layout: running second layout pass
05-15 15:08:06.426 26589-26589/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{ff57dd0 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00d2 app:id/card_jobtype_container} during layout: running second layout pass
05-15 15:08:06.426 26589-26589/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{6bc21c9 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00cf app:id/card_location_container} during layout: running second layout pass
05-15 15:08:06.426 26589-26589/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{adbd0ce V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00d2 app:id/card_jobtype_container} during layout: running second layout pass
05-15 15:08:06.426 26589-26589/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{68adbef V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00cf app:id/card_location_container} during layout: running second layout pass
05-15 15:08:06.426 26589-26589/com.jobforhire.mobile W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout{1fca6fc V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e00d2 app:id/card_jobtype_container} during layout: running second layout pass
```

And I read a couple of post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556607/android-difference-between-invisible-and-gone) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598977/android-requestlayout-improperly-called) that by using `View.GONE`will randomly cause the above error. Is there anyway proper way to use `View.GONE` ? Is it better to set `View.GONE` to an individual object like or encase the object in a layout and apply `View.GONE` to the layout ?